# What is the difference between comma separated or not MATLAB function return?

Tags: matlab

I forgot commas between some returns of a function in MATLAB and it did not complain.

```
function [returnA, returnB]=foo(paramA)
    returnA=ones(1,10).*paramA;
    returnB=magic(4);
end

function[]=voo()
    %typing the return as this
    [A,B]=foo(5);
    %gives the same result as
    [A B]=foo(5);
end
```

My question is: is it exactly the same behavior? I was not able to find it in documentation

Comment: Yes, it is the same behavior.

Comment: If you forget the commas, the editor says "_Best practice is to separate output variables with commas_". This implies that the version without commas is also acceptable

Comment: @LuisMendo So why the _Best practice is to separate output variables_ is _with commas_?

Comment: @EBH because it follows the convention of comma-separated lists: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-14

Comment: Mainly because the code is more readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is the same behavior, as seen with the code you provide in your question.

---

As @LuisMendo points out in the comments, if you look at the MATLAB's [lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) (aka Code Analyzer) message in the editor you'll see:

> Best practice is to separate output variables with commas

Which implies that both syntaxes are valid. As to *why* this is the case I'm not sure, and I can't really find anything specific which tends to point towards "just because." As @rayryeng points out in the comments, it could also have to do with aligning syntax with MATLAB's [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-14).