# Two words inside brackets in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, syntax, brackets

What's that syntax for?

```
[sbox idx] = sort(box);
```

After reading [Sort array elements](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html), I would expect to see something like this:

```
[sbox, idx] = sort(box);
```

but that's not the case as you can see (it's an open sourced project, so it's not mine code). What does it mean?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38462551/2586922)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both lines do exactly the same, like `[1 2 3 4]` and `[1,2,3,4]` define the same vector.

Comment: I didn't know you could define a vector that way, thanks!